# angular-spinner - Fatal error: Unable to find suitable version for angular

Tags: angularjs, spin.js, linemanjs

I want to use [angular-spinner](https://github.com/urish/angular-spinner) in my project (lineman + angularjs). My `bower.json`:

```
{
  "name": "taas",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.2.14",
    "angular-ui-bootstrap": "~0.10.0",
    "jquery": "~2.1.0",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.10.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.10",
    "restangular": "~1.3.1",
    "angular-resource": "~1.2.14",
    "bootstrap": "~3.1.1",
    "font-awesome": "~4.0.3",
    "underscore": "~1.6.0",
    "underscore.string": "~2.3.3",
    "modernizr": "~2.7.2",
    "ng-table": "~0.3.1",
    "jquery-ui": "~1.10.4",
    "jquery.uniform": "~2.1.2",
    "elasticsearch": "~2.1.3",
    "flot": "~0.8.2",
    "angular-flot": "~0.0.2",
    "angular-growl-v2": "~0.6.1",
    "angular-animate": "~1.2.16",
    "spin.js": "~2.0",
    "angular-spinner": "~0.5.0"
  }
}
```

files.js:

```
module.exports = function (lineman) {
    'use strict';
    //Override file patterns here
    return {
        js: {
            vendor: [
                'vendor/bower/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
                'vendor/bower/jquery-ui/ui/jquery-ui.js',
                'vendor/bower/modernizr/modernizr.js',
                'vendor/bower/angular/angular.js',
                'vendor/bower/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',
                'vendor/bower/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
                'vendor/bower/angular-route/angular-route.js',
                'vendor/bower/restangular/dist/restangular.js',
                'vendor/bower/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
                'vendor/bower/underscore/underscore.js',
                'vendor/bower/underscore.string/lib/underscore.string.js',
                'vendor/bower/ng-table/ng-table.src.js',
                'vendor/js/responsive-tables.js',
                'vendor/bower/jquery.uniform/jquery.uniform.js',
                'vendor/bower/flot/jquery.flot.js',
                'vendor/bower/flot/jquery.flot.categories.js',
                'vendor/js/jquery.flot.axislabels.js',
                'vendor/bower/angular-flot/angular-flot.js',
                'vendor/bower/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.angular.js',
                'vendor/bower/angular-growl-v2/build/angular-growl.js',
                'vendor/bower/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
                'vendor/bower/spin.js/spin.js',
                'vendor/bower/angular-spinner/angular-spinner.js'
            ],
            app: [
                'app/js/app.js',
                'app/js/**/*.js'
            ]
        },
        webfonts: {
            root: 'fonts'
        },
        css: {
            vendor: [
                'vendor/bower/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css.map',
                'vendor/bower/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
                'vendor/bower/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css.map',
                'vendor/bower/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css',
                'vendor/bower/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css',
                'vendor/bower/ng-table/ng-table.css',
                'vendor/bower/angular-growl-v2/build/angular-growl.css',
                'vendor/css/**/*.css',
                'app/css/**/*.css'
            ]
        }
    };
};
```

And then

```
$ lineman build
Running "clean:dist" (clean) task

Running "clean:bower" (clean) task

Running "common" task

Running "bower:install" (bower) task
Fatal error: Unable to find suitable version for angular
```

When I remove the `"angular-spinner": "~0.5.0"` line from `bower.json`, the build is successful and the `spin.js` catalog is present in my project.
What? am I doing wrong?

Comment: What bower version? Cannot reproduce with bower 1.3.5

Comment: @TimCastelijns Seems a bower update helped. Thanks!